# How to do a lookup from a dict to a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Actually I have a dict like: `dict = {'A': 'apple', 'B':'banana', 'C':'peas', 'D':'pineapple'}` and a list of dataframes imported using pandas like:

`dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]`. What i want to do is fill an empty column in each df inside the list using information by dict. So it should output something like: `df1{'col1': 'x', 'col2': 'xy','Fruit': 'pineapple'}` and so on...

The criteria to find the relation between both are: the name of files imported and added in the list `dfs`. In this example we can consider the letters `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'`,`'D'`.

Comment: What is your sample data and expected output ?

Comment: What i have done is first, mapped all folders from a path and then, imported all files its has found and put it inside the dfs(list) now, i need to fill the columns of each file to identify each one is what according to the name of imported file. And then concatenate all of them. Its condifence data so i cant load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have list of csv files name

```
names=[...]
```

Then

When you load it

```
l=[pd.read_csv(x).assign(Key=x) for x in names]
```

Now you have the additional column Key contain the file name

And you can concat them

```
df=pd.concat(l)
```

Comment: @Mâncio assign is create a new columns ~ :-) equal to df['New']=x